# Insert an element after a div

Tags: jquery, html, append

I'm having a problem on how to insert a generated element to a specific div. For more clearer view I have this hierarchy of elements

```
<div class="mod-attr-holder" id="chosen-product-16">
  <div class="attr-holder">...</div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-addcart btn-bw-orange button-cart" style="width: 90%;" data-id="chosen-product-16">...</button>
  <a class="btn fontsize18 btn-wishlist text-center">...</a>
  <div class="attr-holder">...</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="option-45" name="option[45]" value="126">
</div>
```

Now I have a button that after clicked it has to insert in that specific div which is after the div.class="attr-holder". After insert it must look like this:

```
<div class="mod-attr-holder" id="chosen-product-16">
  <div class="attr-holder">...</div>
  <div class="attr-holder">...</div> // this is where it has to insert the newly added element
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-addcart btn-bw-orange button-cart" style="width: 90%;" data-id="chosen-product-16">...</button>
  <a class="btn fontsize18 btn-wishlist text-center">...</a>
  <div class="attr-holder">...</div>
  <input type="hidden" id="option-45" name="option[45]" value="126">
</div>
```

I have this code for now:

```
$('.myelement').on('click', function() {
  var product_id = $(this).data('parentid');
  $('#chosen-product-'+product_id + ' .attr-holder').append(html);
});
```

Comment: use insertAfter() :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`insertAfter()`](http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_insertafter). You also should use `:first` because there exist two class by name `attr-holder`. Example:

```
$('.myelement').on('click', function() {
    var product_id = $(this).data('parentid');
    var html = '<div class="attr-holder">...</div>';
    var $selector = $('#chosen-product-'+product_id + ' .attr-holder:first');
    $(html).insertAfter($selector);
    $(this).off("click"); //To disable simultaneous click
});
```

Comment: hi void, it worked. But I have another problem. How do I reset the appended element so it will only insert 1 element. So even if the user  simultaneously clicked the button it will still have only 1 appended element. Sorry for the question.

Comment: Use a flag variable to keep record! ie, Declare `var flag = false;` globally outside the `click()` event. Check inside `click()` event, `if(flag == false){..insert here..; flag = true;}`.

Comment: sorry, what i want is it will overwrite the previous appended element by the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify and find the last or the first element which has **attr-holder** class then **insertAfter** it
for example:

```
$('.myelement').on('click', function() {
    var product_id = $(this).data('parentid');
    var html = '<div class='attr-holder'>...</div>';
    var $selector = $('#chosen-product-'+product_id).children('.attr-holder').last();
    $(html).insertAfter($selector);
});
```

The new HTML tag will be added after the selector in the **mod-attr-holder** hierarchy

Comment: Where is **.myelement** tag? Are you sure that the **click** happens?